# Torsion form and exterior covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensor-calculus, differentiation, lie-algebra

The torsion form can be defined as the exterior covariant derivative of a solder form, $\Theta=d_\omega\theta$. This derivative is always in the fundamental representation of the algebra $\mathfrak g$ or it can be in any representation?

Namely $d_\omega\circ=(d + \omega\wedge_\rho)\circ$ with $\rho$ the fundamental representation of the algebra.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Tried two times and nobody answered...

Comment: You should give a bit more detail here: is your solder form coming from a Cartan connection? What do you mean by "the fundamental representation"? For an arbitrary Lie algebra there is no fixed fundamental representation.